# Recording accelerometer data and share

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on getting accelerometer data when the device is in our hand and moved. I have done a working program for getting accelerometer motion and rotation data. Next is, I want to record it and share via email. I was reading about **recordAccelerometerForDuration**, but I don't know how to use this for recording accelerometer data and share it via email. I could see apple developer help from this link [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMSensorRecorder_class/](http://CMSensorRecorder_class)

Could someone share some sample how to record the value and share in mail to achieve both?

**UPDATE**

I prepared a sample code for recording accelerometer like below,

```
@IBAction func startRecorderAction() {

    guard CMSensorRecorder.isAccelerometerRecordingAvailable() else {

        print("Accelerometer data recording is not available")

        return
    }

    let recorder = CMSensorRecorder()
    let duration = 3.0

    if CMSensorRecorder.isAuthorizedForRecording(){
        print("SensorRecorder authorized")
    }else{
        print("SensorRecorder not authorized")
    }

    recorder.recordAccelerometerForDuration(duration)
    NSOperationQueue().addOperationWithBlock{[unowned recorder] in

        NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(duration)

        let now = NSDate()

        let past = now.dateByAddingTimeInterval(-(duration))

        let data = recorder.accelerometerDataFromDate(past, toDate: now)

        let accelerationData: [CMAcceleration] = data!.map {

            //every $0 is CMRecordedAccelerometerData

            $0.acceleration

        }

        print(accelerationData)

    }
}
```

When I run the app, it says "Accelerometer data recording is not available" . But I am using iPhone 6 and iOS 9.3.1 version. then why this is showing error as accelerometer recording is not available and how to get rid out this?
Could someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

In general will all sensor data not be available when running in the simulator.

SO you will need to build and run towards your device.

But you are on the right track with your code.

Please let us know whether it was the simulator that was the "issue"

Answer (score 0):

Well, old question..but

Sensor recorder is available on Apple Watch from watch OS2.0, and on iPhones from iOS11 and iPhone 7 and up. You have to have device with A10 CPU.